# Selenium type library can't find file driver.start "chrome","https://www.google.com"

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I want to use Excel VBA with Selenium Wrapper to launch Google Chrome and then control Chrome to serve pages I specify so that I can scrape data from them. I can't launch Chrome from VBA.

I'm running Excel 2010. In VBA editor I have added Selenium Type Library to the references. I've verified that I'm running ChromeDriver 2.33.506120. In the code below I know driver is recognized as a driver because I'm getting Intellisense options. I have the ChromeDriver in a folder in Program Files. I have set this folder in the Path list. When I run the code, I get: Run Time Error 2147024894, Automation Error, The system cannot find the file specified. I have also tried driver.start with same results. I have tried changing the name of the browser to "Google Chrome".

```
Sub MyTest()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
    driver.Get "https://www.google.com"
End Sub
```

I expected to launch Chrome. What I get is an error message.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ66t.png)

Comment: Wow you're using ChromeDriver 2.33? My version is somewhere in the 70s. SeleniumBasic usually has pretty verbose (and sometimes almost cryptic) error messages. Can you either type out the entire error or add a screenshot of it? The code you provided works just fine for me btw.

Comment: I am assuming you're likely going to need to use one of the versions of ChromeDriver from here: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. It's good practice to rename your existing driver as `chromedriver_old` and not just replace it.

Comment: Added screen shot of the error message

Comment: Downloaded and instantiated ChromeDriver v75 to match my Chrome version (75). No change. Still get same error message.

Comment: Did you place the chromedriver in the selenium folder?

Comment: chromedriver is in a folder in Program Files. I verified that it is working by using CMD and inserting "chromedriver" . The display showed that chromedriver is working. I don't think my problem is related to chromedriver because I'm getting the exact same problem using IEDriver.

Comment: Ok... but did you try with the .exe in the selenium folder where I suggested? You can also have the containing folder on the environmental path.

Comment: I have put the chromedriver.exe file into the folder "Selenium", which is in the Documents folder. I also put Documents\Selenium\ into the Path list. I didn't change anything else. The chromedriver.exe file is still in a folder ChromeDriver in Program Files. Result is the same. Still getting the "Can't find file" message.